# Using translate.googleapis.com vs translation.googleapis.com

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-translate

I want a proper explanation on what each of translation.googleapis.com and translate.googleapis.com are, and how they differ.

Documentation uses one or the other without any specifics:

- translate: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest
- translation: https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v2/translate

It seems like translation.googleapis.com does not exist in the list of APIs that one can enable (i.e. `gcloud services list --available` only shows `translate.g..`, not `translation*`).

What are these two API endpoints for?

Answer (score 1):

The terms "translation.googleapis.com" and "translate.googleapis.com" are referring to two different things. These two domain names are both translate interfaces provided by Google, but they are different versions.

1. `translation.googleapis.com` is a basic version of the translate interface provided by Google [1].
2. `translate.googleapis.com` is an upgraded version of the translate interface provided by Google [2].

You can review differences between them in [Google Cloud Docs: Compare Basic And Advanced](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/editions) (though they don't explain the difference in endpoint there).